# Javascript Implicit Numbers Conversion

Tags: javascript, numbers, type-conversion

Any help in understanding how it happens?

```
console.log(043) // outputs 35
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Check out how JavaScript interprets number literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates)

Answer (score 2):

It's using the octal number system, due to the leading zero in the numeric literal, the "0" in number.  See http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, number beginning with 0 are treated as octal number.

- Positive octal numbers must begin with 0 (zero) followed by octal
  digit(s).
- Negative octal numbers must begin with -0 followed by octal digit(s).

`35` is the decimal representation of `043`.